# Pointers to class members when iterating with boost::fusion

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-graph, boost-fusion

I have a boost::graph that uses bundled properties like the following:

```
struct Vertex
{
    std::string id;
};
```

If I want to use this information in `boost::dynamic_properties` (e.g. for printing in graphml-format), I can use something like that:

```
template<typename T>
std::string myPrettyPrinter(const T& t);

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    MyGraph g;
    dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("id",
        make_transform_value_property_map(
            & myPrettyPrinter<std::string>,
            get(&Vertex::id, g)
        )
    );
}
```

Since the bundled property might change in the future, I want to be generic about the creation of the `dynamic_properties`. Therefore, I use boost::fusion

```
struct Vertex
{
    std::string id;
};


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Vertex,
    id
)


template<typename T>
std::string myPrettyPrinter(const T& t);


template <typename T_Seq, typename T_Graph>
void member_iterator(boost::dynamic_properties& dp, T_Graph& g)
{
    using namespace boost;
    using Indices = mpl::range_c<
        unsigned,
        0,
        fusion::result_of::size<T_Seq>::value
    >;

    fusion::for_each(
        Indices(),
        [&](auto i)
        {
            using I = decltype(i);
            dp.property(
                fusion::extension::struct_member_name<T_Seq, i>::call(),
                make_transform_value_property_map(
                    & myPrettyPrinter<
                        typename fusion::result_of::value_at<T_Seq, I>::type
                    >,
                    get(
                        // This works but is not generic,
                        // since it relies on the specific
                        // member name "id":
                        & T_Seq::id,
                        g
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    );
}


int main()
{
    MyGraph g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    member_iterator<Vertex>(dp, g);
}
```

My problem is, that I can't find a way to express the line `&T_Seq::id` in a generic way. I have been looking into `fusion::extension::struct_member_name`, but was not successful.

I search for either a generic way to replace the problematic line or a different approach entirely to iterate over the members of `Vertex`.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to define a macro in the new simplified BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT style. If you are willing to explicitly state each member type, I think [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c472952922e32235) could work.

Comment: [c++98](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4d3867cdbdc7609) version.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that your solution works exactly as expected! (tested only the C++14 version). Great job and you should definitely put that code it in a real answer!

Comment: I wholeheartedly concur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the awesome existing answer, I always hesitate to use macros.

In this case I noticed everything became difficult because of the `boost::property_map<Graph, Tag>` interface. I reckoned, you could just use the `vertex_bundle_t` instead.

Here's a simple demo using no macros at all, and that works for the vertex and edge bundles. (You could remove the debug output and add the pretty print hook back in).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddfa109b80867254)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/find.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    std::string id;
    int numeric_value;
};
struct Edge {
    std::string more;
    int awesome_sauce;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Vertex, id, numeric_value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Edge, more, awesome_sauce)

template <typename Tag, typename T_Graph>
void member_iterator(boost::dynamic_properties& dp, T_Graph& g)
{
    using namespace boost;

    using Bundle = typename boost::property_map<T_Graph, Tag>::type;
    using T_Seq  = typename boost::property_traits<Bundle>::value_type;

    using Indices = mpl::range_c<unsigned, 0, fusion::result_of::size<T_Seq>::value>;

    fusion::for_each(
        Indices{},
        [&, bundle=get(Tag{}, g)](auto i) {
            auto name = fusion::extension::struct_member_name<T_Seq, i>::call();
            std::cout << "Adding " << name << "\n";

            dp.property(
                name,
                make_transform_value_property_map(phoenix::at_c<i>(phoenix::arg_names::arg1), bundle)
            );
        }
    );
}

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge>;

int main()
{
    MyGraph g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;

    member_iterator<boost::vertex_bundle_t>(dp, g);
    member_iterator<boost::edge_bundle_t>(dp, g);
}
```

Prints

```
Adding id
Adding numeric_value
Adding more
Adding awesome_sauce
```

Comment: I agree, this looks very clean and generic. However, I can't get the pretty-printing to work with the boost::phoenix calls. If it turns out to be more complicated, I'll create a follow-up question for this.

Comment: Luckily, that's the easy part, so you might just want to ask a new question if you get stuck with that

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out. My mistake was that I was trying `std::bind` and `boost::bind`. After finding out there exists a `phoenix::bind`, things started to work.

Comment: Phoenix is a level more "lazy" than regular binds. Consider using `phoenix::function<>` or just a deferred-callable object for more flexibility. If you share the code I could review whether it can be more friendly/elegant

Comment: thanks for the offer, I created a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919228/binding-a-pretty-printer-to-boostphoenix-actors-when-iterating-with-boostfus

Comment: I think that was worth the question! I'm pretty happy with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35923381/85371) too /cc @cv_and_he

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't get a pointer to a member from the information `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` stores internally(you can, as you discovered, get the member type or name). One possible way to approach this problem is creating a macro that invokes `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` and then stores the additional information. I've chosen to store it like this:

```
template<>
struct pointer_to_member_N<Vertex,0>
{
    static constexpr std::string Vertex::* value = &Vertex::id;
};
```

In order to generate that struct I use the following macros:

---

```
#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR(STRUCT_NAME,MEMBERS) \
namespace your_ns { \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(CREATE_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TRAIT,STRUCT_NAME,BOOST_PP_CAT(YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_0 MEMBERS,_END)) \
}
```

This macro takes the struct name and a sequence of pairs `(type,name)`, and simply opens namespace `your_ns` and calls `CREATE_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TRAIT` with each pair passing `STRUCT_NAME` as data.

---

```
#define CREATE_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TRAIT(R,STRUCT_NAME,INDEX,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
template <> struct pointer_to_member_N<STRUCT_NAME, INDEX>{ static constexpr BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) STRUCT_NAME::* value = &STRUCT_NAME::BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME); };
```

This is the one that actually creates the trait. It takes a parameter `R`(that I have no idea what it does), the name of the struct you are adapting, the index of the current member and a pair `(type,name)`. It uses `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,N,TYPE_AND_NAME)` to get either the type or the name of the member.

---

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>

#include <cstddef>

namespace your_ns
{
    template <typename StructName, int N>
    struct pointer_to_member_N;
}

//Heavily "inspired" from BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_0(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_1
#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_1(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_0
#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_0_END
#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_1_END

#define CREATE_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TRAIT(R,STRUCT_NAME,INDEX,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
template <> struct pointer_to_member_N<STRUCT_NAME, INDEX>{ static constexpr BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) STRUCT_NAME::* value = &STRUCT_NAME::BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME); };

#define YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR(STRUCT_NAME,MEMBERS) \
namespace your_ns { \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(CREATE_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TRAIT,STRUCT_NAME,BOOST_PP_CAT(YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR_FILLER_0 MEMBERS,_END)) \
}


#define ADAPT_STRUCT_AND_SAVE_MEMBERPTR(TYPE,MEMBERS) BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(TYPE,MEMBERS) YOUR_NS_SAVE_MEMBERPTR(TYPE,MEMBERS)

   struct Vertex {
      std::string id;  
      std::size_t index;  
    };


ADAPT_STRUCT_AND_SAVE_MEMBERPTR(
  Vertex, 
  (std::string, id)
  (std::size_t, index)
)





int main() {
Vertex v; 
v.id="A";
v.index=0;

std::cout << std::mem_fn(your_ns::pointer_to_member_N<Vertex,0>::value)(v) << std::endl;
std::cout << v.*your_ns::pointer_to_member_N<Vertex,1>::value << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Cool. Speedy delivery. Again something I can pick apart. Maybe one day I'll get over my phobia of BOOST_PP and macro "programming" in general

Comment: @sehe If you have a weekend and resistance against frustration, take a look, it's quite cool IMO! (And +1 for the excellent answer)

Comment: I found a way to achieve this, that doesn't quite require the macros :) /cc @Columbo

Comment: I like that nothing in my code had to be changed for adapting this solution. I'd like to accept both answers, but since @sehe's solution seems to work around the problem more elegantly, I hope you are OK that I accept his answer.