# Binding a pretty-printer to boost::phoenix actors when iterating with boost::fusion

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-fusion, boost-phoenix

This question is a follow-up to [Pointers to class members when iterating with boost::fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893937/pointers-to-class-members-when-iterating-with-boostfusion/35898342#35898342), where the accepted solution works.

Now, I want not only to add the (primitive) values to the property-map, but use a pretty-printer to improve how the values are displayed. This mechanism will also be used in case the values are not trivial to print.

So, there is some pretty-printer like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string prettyPrinter(const T& t);

template<>
std::string prettyPrinter(const std::string& s)
{
    return "The string id: " + s;
}

template<>
std::string prettyPrinter(const int& i)
{
    return "The int id: " + std::to_string(i);
}
```

and I expanded the solution from the previous question by binding the prettyPrinter to the `boost::phoenix` actor:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/find.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    std::string id;
};

struct Edge {
    int id;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Vertex, id)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Edge, id)

template <typename Tag, typename T_Graph>
void member_iterator(boost::dynamic_properties& dp, T_Graph& g)
{
    using namespace boost;

    using Bundle = typename property_map<T_Graph, Tag>::type;
    using T_Seq  = typename property_traits<Bundle>::value_type;

    using Indices = mpl::range_c<unsigned, 0, fusion::result_of::size<T_Seq>::value>;

    fusion::for_each(
        Indices{},
        [&, bundle=get(Tag{}, g)](auto i) {
            auto name = fusion::extension::struct_member_name<T_Seq, i>::call();
            using TempType = typename fusion::result_of::value_at<T_Seq, decltype(i)>::type;

            //
            // Interesting part starts here:
            //
            dp.property(
                name,
                make_transform_value_property_map(
                    phoenix::bind(
                        prettyPrinter<TempType>,
                        phoenix::at_c<i>(phoenix::arg_names::arg1)
                    ),
                    bundle
                )
            );
        }
    );
}

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge>;

int main()
{
    MyGraph g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;

    member_iterator<boost::vertex_bundle_t>(dp, g);
    member_iterator<boost::edge_bundle_t>(dp, g);
}
```

What I am now looking for is the possibility of a more elegant solution, since @sehe pointed out int a comment, that using `phoenix::bind` might not be the optimal thing to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some random errors in the code you show. None of the `prettyPrinter` overloads would compile. There's no such thing as `Seq`. You adapt the structs for members that don't exist.

All these things aside, you are racing a suboptimal line here: function templates and specializations don't mix well ([Why not specialize function templates, [HSutter,2001]](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)¹).

You seem intent on *hard-coding* your types as well as the pretty-print logic.

**Mantra**:

> *Type deduction and ADL are your friends for extensible mechanisms.*

I'd write the pretty print interface roughly like:

```
#include <string>

namespace pretty_printing
{
    namespace default_impl {
        std::string do_pretty_print(const std::string& s) {
            return "The string id: " + s;
        }

        std::string do_pretty_print(const int i) {
            return "The int id: " + std::to_string(i);
        }
    }

    struct pretty_print_f {
        using result_type = std::string;

        template <typename T> result_type operator()(T&& v) const { 
            using namespace default_impl; // enable ADL
            return do_pretty_print(std::forward<T>(v));
        }
    };
}
```

You can now overload your `do_pretty_print`

- in any way you want (including by providing generic overloads)
- in safe places, like as `friend` members of your types, or as (template) functions in the associated namespace(s) of your types

They will "magically" be picked at the [POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866215/what-is-poi-and-what-does-it-mean).

---

Now, I suggest using `boost::phoenix::function<>` instead of `boost::phoenix::bind` to arrive at a much cleaner call-site:

```
auto name = fusion::extension::struct_member_name<T_Seq, i>::call();
px::function<pretty_printing::pretty_print_f> pretty_print;

dp.property(
    name,
    make_transform_value_property_map(pretty_print(px::at_c<i>(arg1)), bundle)
);
```

Key to the simplification is to let the compiler do what it does best: overload resolution with deduced argument types.

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3b630a37e124d13)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>

namespace pretty_printing
{
    namespace default_impl {
        std::string do_pretty_print(const std::string& s) {
            return "The string id: " + s;
        }

        std::string do_pretty_print(const int i) {
            return "The int id: " + std::to_string(i);
        }
    }

    struct pretty_print_f {
        using result_type = std::string;

        template <typename T> result_type operator()(T&& v) const { 
            using namespace default_impl;
            return do_pretty_print(std::forward<T>(v));
        }
    };
}

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/find.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    std::string id;
    int numeric_value;
};

struct Edge {
    int more;
    std::string awesome_sauce;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Vertex, id, numeric_value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Edge, more, awesome_sauce)

template <typename Tag, typename T_Graph>
void member_iterator(boost::dynamic_properties& dp, T_Graph& g)
{
    using namespace boost;
    namespace px = boost::phoenix;
    using namespace px::arg_names;

    using Bundle = typename property_map<T_Graph, Tag>::type;
    using T_Seq  = typename property_traits<Bundle>::value_type;

    using Indices = mpl::range_c<unsigned, 0, fusion::result_of::size<T_Seq>::value>;

    fusion::for_each(
        Indices{},
        [&, bundle=get(Tag{}, g)](auto i) {

            auto name = fusion::extension::struct_member_name<T_Seq, i>::call();
            px::function<pretty_printing::pretty_print_f> pretty_print;

            dp.property(
                name,
                make_transform_value_property_map(pretty_print(px::at_c<i>(arg1)), bundle)
            );
        }
    );
}

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge>;

int main()
{
    MyGraph g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;

    member_iterator<boost::vertex_bundle_t>(dp, g);
    member_iterator<boost::edge_bundle_t>(dp, g);
}
```

---

¹ See also GotW#49 http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm and [Template Specialization VS Function Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading?lq=1) e.g.

Comment: That improved my actual code a lot! I'll be sure to read your sources as well, thank you!